# Are the event ratios in Appendix B.8 of Intel's Optimization Reference Manual applicable to other microarchitectures?

Tags: performance, x86, intel-pmu

Appendix B.8 of the *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual* (June 2021) contain useful event ratios for performance analysis, workload characterization, and performance tuning.
However, the section title *EVENT RATIOS **FOR INTEL CORE MICROARCHITECTURE*** (emphasis mine) seems to suggest that these ratios are only applicable to the Core microarchitecture.

Can these ratios be used with other microarchitectures? If not, where are such ratios documented?